# Jquery issue in iOS wkwebview

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, uiwebview, wkwebview

jQuery on focus is not working in iOS webview.

I am trying this code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on('focus', '#textarea', function()    {
alert('hello');
}  
</script>
```

It is working in browser and mobile browser also but it is not working in iOS WKwebview.

I have also tried:

```
 <script>
jQuery('#textarea').focus(function() {
 alert('hello');
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you implemented `webView(_:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:)` of `WKUIDelegate`?

Comment: I tried `on focus` and it work on `WKWebView`.

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion, It is working fine now.